# Default tab in lightning

Tags: lightning

I have a requirement to set a default tab in lightning. I have a tab named **Home** and I would like to set the **Companies** tab as the default but without the reordering i.e. home tab should be first, companies second and the default should be companies. I can't seem to find [image]a way to do it without reordering it.

Comment: As far as I know - the first tab is the default one, you cannot set the others as default

Comment: I get it. There is one more requirement that I feel is not possible too. I need to set the Companies tab to 2nd and default for some users, and set the the Home tab as 1st and default for others. Any comments?

Comment: Create 2 different apps as you have described, each assigned to a different profile...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, if it works.

Create a new lightning app and select all the tabs you want to include but don't select home and save the app.
Now open the app. You should see the default tab to company.
Now edit the app and include home and keep it as a first tab.

I hope, your default tab should not change and you will see company as a default landing tab but home would be the first tab as you updated